# Import RestKit in a file that is not UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, restkit

I am using RestKit to send and receive data from a web service.

However, the rest kit headers seem to only want to be imported in files that inherit from `UIViewController`, though i wish to use it in a file that does not inherit from `UIViewController`.

Since it is recognised in my ViewController.h class and I can successfully use it in my ViewController.m class, I assume that the library is installed correctly.

What do I need to do to make it be recognised in files that are not `UIViewController`s? Alternatively, how do I make it recognisable by any file, regardless of where it is in the project ?

btw, the file I am trying to use it in is in the same root folder as my ViewController.h file

Comment: How are you using it? What error do you get? The restriction you describe doesn't make sense so you need to give details of what you do and see.

Comment: I got RestKit/RestKit.h file not found

Comment: How are you importing RestKit? CocoaPods? Including the library? Including the source code? You may need `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>` or just `#import RestKit.h`